# How to pull while deployment in ansible

Tags: git, github, ansible

I am using [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) for configuration management and the following task to clone a Git repo:

```
# Example git checkout from Ansible Playbooks
- git: repo=git://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git
       dest=/srv/checkout
       version=release-0.22
```

This clones the repo with the particular version.

Does it do a `git pull` when run again if the repo already exists? Or does it simply clone the repo all the time? How to do a `git pull` in Ansible if the repo already exists and how can we run a specific command if the repo exists and same if the repo is cloned for the first time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ansible is a declarative tool in which you describe how you want your server/environment to look and Ansible attempts to make that happen. It is also designed to be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) which means that re-running your plays should reproduce the same end result each time as long as nothing underneath has changed.

The [git module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html) also ascribes to this and simply tries to make sure that the remote host has the repo on it and to the version (or branch/tag) that you optionally asked for.

So when you run the git task in your question on a fresh environment it will clone the repo to the destination folder. On future runs, the repo is already there so it simply does a git pull.

If you specify a tag/branch/commit ref to the `update` property then it will simply check that version out and pull that.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But how to do git revert than?

Comment: A `git revert` is a forward change that affects your repo and not something you'd typically want to use Ansible for (or any automated tool other than maybe a build tool). Use Ansible to state what version of your code (ie. branch/tag/commit ref) that you want on the host and leave it at that.

Comment: When I try to run the command a second time, I get an error that the destination path already exists and is not empty...

Comment: @CGFoX then you should create your own question showing your code and explaining what doesn't work for you. If you think it's relevant then that question should link back to this one for context

Answer (score 4):

This works for me using a shell command:

```
- hosts: myserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: pull changes
    shell: chdir=/path/whereis/myrepo git pull https://mygituser:mypassword@bitbucket.org/company/myrepo.git master
```

i had to specify the remote url using user and password because it hangs with simple "git pull".